# Auth0 Authorization throws Unauthorized

Tags: angularjs, jwt, auth0

I try to implement Auth0 in my Single-Page-App using angular.

here are the scripts i loaded for auth0:

```
<!-- Auth0's lock widget library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.0.js"></script>
<!-- Angular cookie wrapper library for client cookies -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<!-- Auth0's Angular SDK Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-angular-4.js"></script>
<!-- Angular wrapper for localStorage and sessionStorage. Defaults to ng-cookies if not available -->
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/auth0/angular-storage/master/dist/angular-storage.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<!-- Angular wrapper library for JWT-->
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/auth0/angular-jwt/master/dist/angular-jwt.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

But the Token has an invalid Signature and is always unauthorized when i try the api call for the user information here : [Api to get user data](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#!#get--userinfo)

the token is stored in the local storage in the following eventhandler

```
   authProvider.on('loginSuccess', ['$location', 'profilePromise', 'idToken', 'store',
          function($location, profilePromise, idToken, store) {

            profilePromise.then(function(profile) {
              store.set('user', profile.email);
              store.set('token', idToken);
            });

            $location.path('/');
        }]);
```

The debugger from jwt.io always says invalid Signature  when i try to decode my jwt even with my client secret.

Did i do something wrong ? Why is my token Signature invalid ? Why is my token unauthorized? Does the Api page even work on actual data ?

### EDIT:

I found out that i used the wrong api call i used the one for auth0-access-tokens instead for JWTs.

But still the JWT Debugger shows invalid Signature

Comment: Can you make sure your ClientID is the same as the ClientID you are using in the application?

Comment: Another thing you might want to check is the client secret on dashboard is Base64 encoded, can you make sure your server side accounts for that?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: are you still facing unauthorized?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `idToken`, you should be calling the [/tokeninfo endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#!#post--tokeninfo). Be sure to follow the required format: it should be a `POST`, with content type `json` containing this payload:

```
{
  "id_token" : "[the token]"
}
```

However, you probably don't want to do any of this. The call to `/tokeninfo` will get you the user profile, but the SDK already does that for you after authenticating the user. The same user profile is available in the callback from `profilePromise` here:

```
authProvider.on('loginSuccess', ['$location', 'profilePromise', 'idToken', 'store',
      function($location, profilePromise, idToken, store) {

        profilePromise.then(function(profile) {
          // 'profile' contains the same information that 
          // you would get calling '/tokeinfo' or '/userinfo' 
          // so consider storing the whole 'profile' instead
          // of just 'profile.email'
          store.set('user', profile.email);
          store.set('token', idToken);
        });

        $location.path('/');
    }]);
```

Comment: I have a web app and a node server and the node server calls the api to verify that the apps token is valid and based on the role the user has the server decides which DB stuff gets retrieved for the local use. Now i fight a little with http